# Getting Ubuntu from scratch as installation USB without having Ubuntu on my desktop

Tags: system-installation, usb

I am working to help a charity that receives computers cast off by hospitals and schools. I don't want to have to install Ubuntu on my own desktop in order to get access to all the download features for a bootable USB.

Is it possible to download the whole program in a bootable/installable state onto a USB key so that I can use it to install on another computer, often one with a password protected and time-limited blocked Windows OS, in order to completely install Ubuntu over Windows?

Comment: It's not necessary to install Ubuntu. Use [rufus](https://rufus.ie) to create a bootable usb.

Comment: @Thomas Baxter Find Etcher at https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The ISO file you use to create a LiveUSB should be checked for download errors following http://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 , the 'checksum' process which runs the values of the downloaded ISO file through a formula. If you 'check' the 'sums' and get the save value as the original ISO file has, they the ISO file arrived completely correct.

Installation, as per Canonical, Ubuntu's publishers, is typically done following these instructions on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 using a 4GB or larger USB Flash Drive. You don't need to install Ubuntu onto your PC to do that.

> 1) rufus.ie is a Windows app which should be installed as any other
>   Windows app. It does not go on the USB key.
>
> 2) Ubuntu is put on the USB key by running Rufus after you have
>   downloaded the ISO file of Ubuntu Desktop.
>
> 3) I am not sold on Etcher being better than Rufus, and neither is
>   Canonical, the publishers of Ubuntu, because their tutorial says to
>   use Rufus. Some folks like Etcher because it's not Windows-only.

Once you make a LiveUSB, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0.

Comment: Thank you to those who have offered help. I have been away from computer 'lingo' for awhile. Certain cryptic responses may make sense to you folks but not to me. Please clarify for me, if you will, as per the following. I tried downloading both Ubuntu and Rufus. They disappeared into the computer and eventually I found them buried in Microsoft Edge subfolders for downloads. I am not clear about 1) should Rufus program end up on the USB key? 2) does Ubuntu go on the same stick, 3) why Etcher is better, what to watch for, how to regulate; 4) what is a checksum, and how to do. Please help me.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. This is slowly starting to make sense. So when I clicked on Rufus it formatted the key, but installed itself on the computer (inside Microsoft Edge downloads). And the Ubuntu file was in the same place. So now, do I click on the Rufus execution file and then it will direct me so I can get Ubuntu on the stick? Then after that, do I run the checksum process on the stick?

Comment: @Thomas Baxter A) Run checksum on downloaded ISO following link in first full paragraph of my answer. B) Launch Rufus app, tell it where the ISO file, choose GPT, make LiveUSB drive.